# Picking up an array of values from php request and running a mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, get

I have this table which contains the following columns.

- Id
- place_id
- name
- latitude
- longitude
- offers

I have to get the offers given an array of place IDs. But the way I have implemented this, it doesn't return any results. Below is my request.

```
http://localhost:8001/googleplaces/getOffers.php?place_id[]=%22epc888%22&place_id[]=%22epc999%22
```

Below is the PHP script I wrote.

```
<?php
    $response = array();
    $pid =array();
    require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';
    $db = new DB_CONNECT();
    if (isset($_GET["place_id"])) {
       $pid = $_GET['place_id'];

       $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM places WHERE place_id IN ($pid)");

       if (!empty($result)) {
       // check for empty result
       if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

        $result = mysql_fetch_array($result);

        $place = array();
        $place["place_id"] = $result["place_id"];
        $place["offers"] = $result["offers"];
        // success
        $response["success"] = 1;

        // user node
        $response["place"] = array();

        array_push($response["place"], $place);

        // echoing JSON response
           echo json_encode($response);
           } else {
              // no product found
               $response["success"] = 0;
               $response["message"] = "No offers found";

              // echo no users JSON
              echo json_encode($response);
           }
        } else {
        // no product found
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "No offers found";

           // echo no users JSON
           echo json_encode($response);
         }
        } else {
        // required field is missing
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "place_id is missing";

        // echoing JSON response
      echo json_encode($response);
     }
    ?>
```

Though there are couple of records satisfying the above request, this is the response I get.

```
{"success":0,"message":"No offers found"}
```

What am I doing wrong here? Please advice. I am new to PHP.

Comment: Why did you use *mysql_* -- these functions are deprecated? Also your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: Yes this is a small code piece called through an android application of mine. So I don't mind those :) Could you please tell me where I have gone wrong here? :(

Comment: @trincot I did as you said. Please refer the edited question. But I still am getting only one output. Please help :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As PHP detects the URL parameter `place_id[]` is of array type, it will present the values as an array. However, you inject the *$pid* into your SQL. PHP will raise a warning about this, but will still do an implicit conversion and continue. If for instance, if the array was *(1, 2, 3)*, then it would be converted to the string *"Array.1,2,3"*, which leads to invalid SQL syntax.

The very quick solution would be to turn that array into a comma-separated string, like this:

```
$pid = implode(",", $_GET['place_id']);
```

However, and this is important: your code is vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). If someone knows the URL to send to your PHP code, they can quite a lot of damage! You should use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) (and move to *mysqli* or *PDO*!) with arguments instead.

You should also turn your results processing into a loop to treat all records, and collect them in an array. So replace the `if` with a `while`, and directly populate *$response["place"]*. Note that your `if` was overwriting the original *$results* result-set with the array of the first record, which makes you lose the original *$result* object. But you'll need it for looping over it. So I introduce the variable *$row*:

```
// check for empty result
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // user node
    $response["place"] = array(); // array of places
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $response["place"][] = array(
            "place_id" => $row["place_id"],
            "offers" => $row["offers"]
        );
    }
    // success
    $response["success"] = 1;
    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

Comment: After adding the line, I am getting only one record. The other one is not returned. Is the way I'm returning the records correct? Does the $place array hold all the output?

Comment: Use while loop, see updated answer. also note you were assigning to `$result` while getting from `$result` ---> really bad code!

Comment: Thanks a lot mate! nailed it.

Answer (score 1):

This: `$_GET['place_id']` is an array in your example, so you need to treat it like one in your query.

So you could do this:

```
$pid = implode(",", $_GET['place_id']);
```

Not the best way, but it should get it working. You probably want to escape and sanitize that though.

---

To get all results you need to iterate through them like:

```
    // success
    $response["success"] = 1;
    // user node
    $response["place"] = array();

    while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $response["place"][] = array( 
            "place_id" => $result["place_id"],
            "offers" => $result["offers"],
        );
    }
```

Comment: After adding the line, I am getting only one record. The other one is not returned. Is the way I'm returning the records correct? Does the $place array hold all the output?

Comment: Yes, I thought that was how you wanted it, if you need to return all results, then you need to iterate through them. I can update my answer.

Comment: Im getting this error after placing your code :(  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ')' in C:\wamp\www\googleplaces\getOffers.php on line 26

Comment: Thanks mate I found the solution :)